# Excel Index Partial match

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, excel-2013

I have Sheet1 with column A listing every single country in alphabetical order..

```
     A
 1   Afghanistan<
 2   Albania
 3   Algeria
 4   American Samoa
 5   Andorra
 ----------
 228 United Kingdom
 229 United States
 etc
```

I have Sheet2 column A with empty cells with adjacent cells in column B listing address details

```
   A           B
 1 empty cell  Unit 3, Road;London, United Kingdom
 2 empty cell  Building 1, Road, TX, United States
 3 empty cell  8th floor, Business Park, India 1234
 etc
```

What I would like to know is how can I obtain the country within the address details in sheet2 column B and place them in Sheet2 column A, based on a match on the list of countries in Sheet1 column A.

Part of the problem is there is no coherent method as to how to country is placed within the address; could be at the end or in the middle of the address.

I have tried various index match formulas with no luck

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it with the reference table being in A1:B7, and lookups being A10:B10 onwards down. The formula is for these cells. You can adjust it for Sheet1/2!.

Assuming your data is in B10 onwards, and your reference data was in B1:B7, you can write this formula in A10 `=INDEX($B$1:$B$7,MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND($B$1:$B$7,B10)),-1,1)*(ROW($B$1:$B$7)-ROW($B$1)+1)))`. This is an array formula, so please hit `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` for excel to read it as an array formula.

[image: Sample screenshot]
(*In the screenshot, I have pasted the table in A10:B12 as values only in D10:E12*)

Answer (score 0):

Text to Columns with a comma delimiter

[image]

Comment: Sorry I should of explained it's not alway the same style delimiter, plus I have over 3000 rows of addresses